# freeDiameter - fd_sess_handler_create

Tags: c, free-diameter

I just had one question about "fd_sess_handler_create" function in freeDiameter library.

Well, in test_app extension, there is a ta_cli_init function to initialize the client procedure, this block was compiled fine when the code was in C :

```
int ta_cli_init(void)
{
  CHECK_FCT( fd_sess_handler_create(&ta_cli_reg, (void*)free, NULL, NULL) );
  CHECK_FCT( fd_event_trig_regcb(ta_conf->signal, "test_app.cli", ta_cli_test_message ) );
  return 0;
}
```

However, as soon as i changed the code to C++ , the compiler started to nagging about "cleanup" parameter (second param) that I had to change the code to make the it compiled:

```
void sess_handler_free(struct sess_state * state, os0_t sid, void * opaque)
{
}

int ta_cli_init(void)
{
  CHECK_FCT( fd_sess_handler_create(&ta_cli_reg, &sess_handler_free, NULL, NULL) );
  CHECK_FCT( fd_event_trig_regcb(ta_conf->signal, "ocs_app.cli", ta_cli_test_message ) );

  return 0;
}
```

The code is now can be compiled, but because i wasnt sure about cleanup context, as you see i left it empty.

Could you plz explain to me what exactly should be cleaned up in my custom sess_handler_free function body ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `sess_handler_free` needs to free off `struct sess_state` **plus** any additional data structures your code has appended to it.

If you don't have any additional data structures, you should just use be able to make `sess_handler_free` call `free(state)`.  (Passing the free function directly is another way of doing this.)

If you do have additional data structures, you need to find them from the `struct sess_state` and free them off using `delete` if they were created using `new` or `free` if they were created using `malloc`.

See [`diameap_cli_sess_cleanup`](https://github.com/Metaswitch/freeDiameter/blob/master/extensions/app_diameap/diameap_server.c#L87) as an example implementation - notice that it checks for `methodData`, `user.password` and `user.userid` fields and frees them off if present, before freeing the `struct sess_state` itself - this extension allocated these fields, so it is responsible for freeing them.